# How to add class to an element create by appendChild

Tags: javascript, appendchild

I want to ask how to add a class for an element I create by appendChild in javascript

```
document.forms[0].appendChild(document.createElement("input"));
```

How to add a class for the input element I created?

I just use Javascript and I don't like jQuery, please send answer in pure javascript.

Answer (score 53):

> I want to ask how to add a class for an element I create by appendChild in javascript

Like any other element you have a reference. It doesn't matter if it's created in JS via `createElement`, or you obtained a reference to the node in another way. Assuming `input` contains the reference to your node:

```
var input = document.createElement("input");
```

You can either use [className](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.className):

```
input.className = "foo";
```

[classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.classList):

```
input.classList.add("foo");
```

[setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.setAttribute):

```
input.setAttribute("class", "foo");
```

The first one is widely supported by any browser, so I strongly suggest that one unless you're not in a modern browser and you want to manipulate each class you set, so `classList` will be more useful. I strongly avoid the latter, because with `setAttribute` you're going to set the HTML's attribute not the class name of the JS object: then the browser will map that value to the JS's property but in some cases it will fails (see, for instance, some versions of IE) so the class won't be applied even if the HTML node will have that attribute.

Notice that all the methods above are working despite how to `HTML` node reference is obtained, so also with:

```
var input = document.getElementById("my-input");
```

And so on.

In your case, because `appendChild` returns the reference to the node appended, you can also write everyting in one statement:

```
document.forms[0]
    .appendChild(document.createElement("input"))
    .className = "foo";
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: several solutions with informative explanations = excellent answer!

Comment: `classList`: exactly what I was looking for. Super cool ! :)

Answer (score 9):

You need a variable for the created element.

```
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.className = 'class_to_add';
document.forms[0].appendChild(input);
```

***Update:***

`.appendChild` return the child, so you could also do it with out a variable:

```
document.forms[0].appendChild(document.createElement("input")).className = "class_to_add";
```

Comment: Why is this downvoted ? I was about to post the same answer...

Comment: @Downvoter  Could you explain what's wrong?

Comment: Hmm, I would guess because the proper way to add/remove attributes to an element is via setAttribute and getAttribute.

Comment: For the class, I think the recommended way is to *not* use setAttribute.

Comment: What if I want to keep a reference to the created element? (input). Can I still create the whole thing in one line of code?

Answer (score 1):

Use the setAttribute and getAttribute methods:

```
var i = document.createElement('input'); 
i.setAttribute('class', 'myclass');
document.forms[0].appendChild(i);
```

Comment: Look at this: http://www.tgerm.com/2009/02/javascript-ie-setattributeclass-or.html

Answer (score 1):

Like:

```
document.forms[0].appendChild(document.createElement("input")).className = "class_to_add";
```

Comment: @xdazz [I don't think so](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.appendChild)

Comment: @dystroy Yep, missed that, It's odd that `appendChild` will return child not the element self.

Comment: But this is exactly what was asked, no? *"I don't now how to add a class for the input element I created."* So, `appendChild` will return the child appended, in that case the `input` ones.